# Fast multiplication of a series of matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

What is the fastest possible way to run:

```
    reduce(lambda x,y : x@y, ls)
```

in python?

for a list of matrices `ls`.  I don't have an Nvidia GPU, but I do have a lot of CPU cores to work with. I thought I could make the process work in parallel (split it to `log` iterations), but it seems that for small (`1000x1000`) matrix, this is actually worst. Here is the code I tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
from itertools import zip_longest

def matmul(x):
    if x[1] is None:
        return x[0]
    return x[1]@x[0]

def fast_mul(ls):
    while True:
        
        n = len(ls)
        if n == 0:
            raise Exception("Splitting Error")
        if n == 1:
            return ls[0]
        if n == 2:
            return ls[1]@ls[0]

        with Pool(processes=(n//2+1)) as pool:
            ls = pool.map(matmul, list(zip_longest(*[iter(ls)]*2)))
```

Comment: That's odd -- you seem to be doing a sensible thing already (making use of the fact that array multiplication is associative).  Does it help if you put the whole `while` loop inside a single `with Pool(process=num_cores) as pool:` (for an appropriate value of `num_cores`), and remove the `with` statement inside the loop?

Comment: Hey! it seems to speed it up a bit, but it is still slower than the naive approach.

Comment: @YotamVaknin I wouldn't create as many processes as multiplications are needed, just use the system concurrency (the default), the point of the pool is to reuse processes when there are many tasks at hand.

Comment: Other than that, you can simplify the code to `pool.starmap(matmul, zip(ls[::2], ls[1::2]))`, and I would change it to handle inputs with size that are not a power of two, with `ls_next = pool.starmap(...)` and then `if len(ls) % 2 != 0: ls_next.append(ls[-1])`, then `ls = ls_next`.

Comment: numpy has a `multi_dot` function

Comment: Also, keep in mind that sending all that data around takes time. Using numpy's builtin release of the GIL is likely going to be faster.

Comment: `matmul/dot` makes good use of the BLAS/etc libraries.  Depending on the OS, those should make good use of multiple cores.  Since multiprocessing won't reduce the total amount of calculations, its communication costs might not be worth it.

Comment: I haven't done much multiprocessing, but seems to me that the arrays should be grouped in a binary tree, e.g. ((1,2), (3,4)) ((5,6),(7,8)) as opposed to ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6)...).  A problem here is that eventually the results have to be chained, and thus can't be preformed in a true parallel fashion (independent of each other).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Threw in yet another possible function

EDIT: I added the results with [`np.linalg.multi_dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html), expecting it would be faster than the rest but actually it is much slower somehow. I suppose it is design with other kind of use case in mind.

---

I'm not sure you will be able to get much faster than that. Here are a few different implementations of the reduction for the case where the data is a 3D array of square matrices:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def matmul_n_naive(data):
    return reduce(np.matmul, data)

# If you don't care about modifying data pass copy=False
def matmul_n_binary(data, copy=True):
    if len(data) < 1:
        raise ValueError
    data = np.array(data, copy=copy)
    n, r, c = data.shape
    dt = data.dtype
    s = 1
    while (n + s - 1) // s > 1:
        a = data[:n - s:2 * s]
        b = data[s:n:2 * s]
        np.matmul(a, b, out=a)
        s *= 2
    return np.array(a[0])

def matmul_n_pool(data):
    if len(data) < 1:
        raise ValueError
    lst = data
    with Pool() as pool:
        while len(lst) > 1:
            lst_next = pool.starmap(np.matmul, zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))
            if len(lst) % 2 != 0:
                lst_next.append(lst[-1])
            lst = lst_next
    return lst[0]

@nb.njit(parallel=False)
def matmul_n_numba_nopar(data):
    res = np.eye(data.shape[1], data.shape[2], dtype=data.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(len(data)):
        res = res @ data[i]
    return res

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def matmul_n_numba_par(data):
    res = np.eye(data.shape[1], data.shape[2], dtype=data.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(len(data)):  # Numba knows how to do parallel reductions correctly
        res = res @ data[i]
    return res

def matmul_n_multidot(data):
    return np.linalg.multi_dot(data)
```

And a test:

```py
# Test
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(10, 100, 100) * 2 - 1
b1 = matmul_n_naive(a)
b2 = matmul_n_binary(a)
b3 = matmul_n_pool(a)
b4 = matmul_n_numba_nopar(a)
b5 = matmul_n_numba_par(a)
b6 = matmul_n_multidot(a)
print(np.allclose(b1, b2))
# True
print(np.allclose(b1, b3))
# True
print(np.allclose(b1, b4))
# True
print(np.allclose(b1, b5))
# True
print(np.allclose(b1, b6))
# True
```

Here are some benchmarks, it seems there is no consistent winner but the "naive" solution is pretty good all around, binary and Numba vary, the process pool is not really good and `np.linalg.multi_dot` does not seem to be very advantageous with square matrices.

```py
import numpy as np

# 10 matrices 1000x1000
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(10, 1000, 1000) * 0.1 - 0.05
%timeit matmul_n_naive(a)
# 121 ms ± 6.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_binary(a)
# 165 ms ± 3.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_numba_nopar(a)
# 108 ms ± 510 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_numba_par(a)
# 244 ms ± 7.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit matmul_n_multidot(a)
# 132 ms ± 2.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# 200 matrices 100x100
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(200, 100, 100) * 0.1 - 0.05
%timeit matmul_n_naive(a)
# 4.4 ms ± 226 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_binary(a)
# 13.4 ms ± 299 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_numba_nopar(a)
# 9.51 ms ± 126 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_numba_par(a)
# 4.93 ms ± 146 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_multidot(a)
# 1.14 s ± 22.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# 300 matrices 10x10
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(300, 10, 10) * 0.1 - 0.05
%timeit matmul_n_naive(a)
# 526 µs ± 953 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_binary(a)
# 152 µs ± 508 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_pool(a)
# 610 ms ± 5.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit matmul_n_numba_nopar(a)
# 239 µs ± 1.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_numba_par(a)
# 175 µs ± 422 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_multidot(a)
# 3.68 s ± 87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# 1000 matrices 10x10
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(1000, 10, 10) * 0.1 - 0.05
%timeit matmul_n_naive(a)
# 1.56 ms ± 4.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_binary(a)
# 392 µs ± 790 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_pool(a)
# 727 ms ± 12.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit matmul_n_numba_nopar(a)
# 589 µs ± 356 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_numba_par(a)
# 451 µs ± 1.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit matmul_n_multidot(a)
# Never finished...
```

Comment: Could you time my 25-or-fewer hack? It's not a serious solution, but I just had to post it.

Comment: Actually, I've also found `multi_dot`. I suspect that will be fastest.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added that to the benchmarks expecting to find that, but it seems much slower in most cases. I guess it must be optimized for some specific kind of use cases.

Comment: I did some simple timings. It's worth looking at a non-square case. I think you will see a pretty big difference.

Comment: The code for `multi_dot` (and sub functions) is found in `np.linalg.linalg.py`.  Apart from the calls to `np.dot` it's all python, focusing on the 'best' order for chaining the `dot` calls.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function to do this: [`np.linalg.multi_dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html), supposedly optimized for the best evaluation order:

```
np.linalg.multi_dot(ls)
```

In fact the docs say something very close to your original phrasing:

> Think of [`multi_dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html) as:
>
> ```
> def multi_dot(arrays): return functools.reduce(np.dot, arrays)
> ```

You could also try `np.einsum`, which will allow you to multiply up to 25 matrices:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

ls = [...]
index = ','.join(ascii_lowercase[x:x + 2] for x in range(len(ls)))
index += f'->{index[0]}{index[-1]}'
np.einsum(index, *ls)
```

**Timing**

Simple case:

```
ls = np.random.rand(100, 1000, 1000) - 0.5

%timeit reduce(lambda x, y : x @ y, ls)
4.3 s ± 76.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit reduce(np.matmul, ls)
4.35 s ± 84.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit reduce(np.dot, ls)
4.86 s ± 68.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.linalg.multi_dot(ls)
5.24 s ± 66.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

More complicated case:

```
ls = [x.T if i % 2 else x for i, x in enumerate(np.random.rand(100, 2000, 500) - 0.5)]

%timeit reduce(lambda x, y : x @ y, ls)
7.94 s ± 96.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit reduce(np.matmul, ls)
7.91 s ± 33.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit reduce(np.dot, ls)
9.38 s ± 111 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.linalg.multi_dot(ls)
2.03 s ± 52.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Notice that the up-front work done by `multi_dot` has negative benefit in the straightforward case (and more suprisingly, `lambda` works faster than the raw operator), but saves 75% of the time in the less straightforward case.

So just for completeness, here is a less non-square case:

```
ls = [x.T if i % 2 else x for i, x in enumerate(np.random.rand(100, 400, 300) - 0.5)]

%timeit reduce(lambda x, y : x @ y, ls)
245 ms ± 8.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit reduce(np.matmul, ls)
245 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit reduce(np.dot, ls)
284 ms ± 12.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.linalg.multi_dot(ls)
638 ms ± 12.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So really it seems that for most general cases, your original `reduce` call is actually about as good as you need to get. My only suggestion would be to use `operator.matmul` instead of the lambda.

Comment: Why is this limited to multiplying 25 matrices? Does it have to do with the number of letters in the alphabet?

Comment: @jakub. Fixed. Thanks for the catch :)

Comment: @jdehesa. Seems like `multi_dot` really is much slower in most cases. Just happens to work better in that one case.

Comment: My memory from past questions is that `multi_dot` only makes a difference if the arrays differ in shape.  It takes some time at the start to figure out which `dot` combinations will reduce the problem size the fastest.  If the arrays are all the same size, it doesn't help, and with extra upfront work will be slower.